# Python sum of function output values

Tags: python

I have the following function in a Python application called `Solfec`:

```
n0 = 330

n1 = 1027

n2 = 1201

n3 = 1023


def make_rock (x, y, z, r, kind, material, solfec):      
    m = randint (8, 64)     
    points = [ ]

    for n in range (m):        
        points.append (x + r * (1.0 - random()))        
        points.append (y + r * (1.0 - random()))        
        points.append (z + r * (1.0 - random()))          

    hull = HULL (points, 1, 1)
    rocks = BODY (solfec, kind, hull, material)

SURFACE_MATERIAL (solfec, model = 'SIGNORINI_COULOMB', friction = 0.5)

bulk = BULK_MATERIAL (solfec, 'KIRCHHOFF', young = 1.5E5, poisson = 0.25, density = 2.6E-6)

 # choose the rock radius(r,r1,r2,r3):

r = 16

r1 = 13

r2 = 11

r3 = 10


aint = int(w - 10)

bint = int(d - 10)

cint0 = int(p*n0/16)

cint1 = int(p*n1/16)

cint2 = int(p*n2/16)

cint3 = int(p*n3/16)


for a in range (10, aint, 30):

  for b in range (10 , bint , 30):

    for c in range (20 , 20 + cint0, p):

        make_rock (a, b, c, r, 'RIGID', bulk, solfec)


    for a1 in range (10, aint, 30):

     for b1 in range (10, bint, 30):

      for c1 in range (50, 50 + cint1, p):

        make_rock (a1, b1, c1, r1, 'RIGID', bulk, solfec)


    for a2 in range (10, aint, 30):

     for b2 in range (10, bint, 30):

      for c2 in range (40, 40 + cint2, p):

        make_rock (a2, b2, c2, r2, 'RIGID', bulk, solfec)


     for a3 in range (10, aint, 30):

       for b3 in range (10, bint, 30):

        for c3 in range (30, 30 + cint3, p):

         make_rock (a3, b3, c3, r3, 'RIGID', bulk, solfec)
```

Which creates some sort of geometric objects and assigns some properties to them (HULL, BODY) by means of a for loop.

The application I am using allows me to output the volume of each body created, by means of:

```
rocks.volume
```

So if I write:

```
print rocks.volume
```

I obtain a printed list of all the volumes.

I need to sum those values,how can I do it? If I use:

```
print sum(rocks.volume)
```

I get `float` object is not iterable.

So I thought I need to create a unique list of all of those output values and then sum them up with the normal `sum()` command.

Comment: I've tried to format your code so that it's readable. I hope the indention is correct.

Comment: Please post the code that defines `rocks`.

Comment: What does `type(rocks.volume)` return?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a list with all the rocks somewhere you can do:

```
    sum((rock.volume for rock in rocks_list))
```

If you don't then we need more info about what is the rest of the code from that method (e.g. what does it return, and where is it called) and also where do you need this sum to be computed and how often.

I'll try to edit my answer according to your comments but it still would be a lot easier if you just edited your question, provide ALL the code from the make_rock method and where you call it. Now if you **only need** the sum of the volumes you can do:

```
    sum_v = 0
    #These are your for loops
    for a in ...
        for b in ...
            for c in ...
                sum_v += make_rock(a, b, c ...)
```

And now at the end of make_rock make sure you have:

```
    return rocks.volume
```

Comment: a series of <type 'float> lines..one per rock element created in the loop..I just need to put all of of those values in the same list

Comment: I think there is no list like rocks_list..usually one creates objects one by one and then can calls the function object.volume for each of them..in my case I had to create more then 3600 similar objects,so I used a loop. Therefore if I put the object.volume command inside of the loop I get more then 3600 volume values as output of this function. I can't avoid using a loop,so that's my problem.

Comment: If I try to ceate a list like :

Comment: [rocks.volume] I just get a series of lists with one value of volume in each one instead of a unique one with all the values stored in it..

Comment: This is the for loop which calls the function make_rock:

Comment: for a in range (10, aint, 30):
  for b in range (10 , bint , 30):
    for c in range (20 , 20 + cint0, p):
      make_rock (a, b, c, r, 'RIGID', bulk, solfec)

Comment: you can use the 'edit' button below your question to add the extra pieces of code needed, it's harder like this to udnerstand what you mean.

Comment: I have edited the code, is it clearer now?if you have any question feel free to ask